# Kohana 3.3 routing to subdirectory

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3

I'm new to Kohana and am stuck with routing to a subdirectory, It keeps giving me a url not found on server.

In the `bootstrap.php` I have this Route defined:

```
Route::set('store', 'store(/<action>)')
    ->defaults(array(
        'directory'  => 'store',
        'controller' => 'main',
        'action'     => 'index',
    ));
```

the store controller is stored in `application/classes/Controller/Store/Main.php`

To test it the controller is only returning some text to the page:

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct script access.');

class Controller_Store_Main extends Controller
{
    public function action_index()
    {
        $this->response->body('Store Main Page');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same works for me.

1. What Kohana version do you use? This example is for 3.3 only.
2. Your route must be defined before `default` route.

Comment: Thank you, yeah I am using 3.3 and didn't see anything in the documentation stating that all routes must be defined before the default route. that fixed .

Comment: Default route is a "catch-all" route, so there is no chance that any route after it will be used.